# What is wrong about this seemingly simple false proof?

Tags: calculus, inequality, fake-proofs

It came accros my mind when doing an exercise in calculus. Consider the following inequalities:

$1\leq 2\leq 5$
$1\leq 3\leq 5$

Adding the equaions up is totally fine. But subtracting them, we get:

$0\leq 2-3\leq 0$ ??

I fail to understand what is wrong with this step. If someone could formally explain it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Knowing that $a≥b$ and $c≥d$ does not tell you that $a-c≥b-d$, as you have noticed.

Comment: You can add the left and right sides in such cases , but not subtract it because the order need not be preserved.

Comment: Using lulu's comment you only have $a-b\ge 0$ and $c-d\ge0$ , but this does not imply $a-b\ge c-d$ which you woule need.

Comment: The more interesting question is “What is right with that step”? Why one can subtract inequalities like that? You can add them, because it is very clear that if you add two small numbers it’s even smaller than the sum of two big numbers. What’s the intuition behind subtracting inequalities like that? Why did it have to work to be surprised that it didn’t?

Comment: I think that I just got too used to the fact that you can add _equations_ to inequalities. When doing that, all I'm doing is adding the same (hence _equation_) to both sides, and that is totally legal. But when adding an **inequality**, I am not necessarily adding the same to both sides, hence I am not necessarily preserving  the inequality/equality. Now it's clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with inequalities, addition of inequalities that are both true is a valid operation that preserves the truth of the individual inequalities. However, subtraction requires a bit more caution, especially in how it affects the direction and integrity of the inequalities. Let's clarify the situation with your example.

You start with two true inequalities:

1. $1 \leq 2 \leq 5$
2. $1 \leq 3 \leq 5$

Adding them is straightforward, and the result would indeed preserve the truth of the inequalities since addition is a direct operation that doesn't invert the direction of the inequalities.

However, when you "subtract" the inequalities, what you're effectively trying to do is not directly supported by the rules of inequalities. Let's break it down:- From $1 \leq 2$ and $1 \leq 3$, if you subtract the second inequality from the first,
you're not actually performing a direct operation on the
inequalities themselves. Instead, you might be thinking of
subtracting the terms within each inequality, which isn't a valid
operation in the context of manipulating inequalities directly.

The
resulting expression you derived, $0 \leq 2 - 3 \leq 0$, which
simplifies to $0 \leq -1 \leq 0$, is not true because $-1$ is
not greater than or equal to $0$.

The confusion arises from
attempting an operation (subtraction) that doesn't directly apply to
inequalities the way addition or multiplication by a positive number
does. The correct approach when dealing with inequalities and
considering operations like subtraction is to work within the
constraints of each inequality separately and avoid assuming that
operations that apply to equations (like subtraction) will operate
the same way on inequalities.

Answer (score 3):

The subtraction is equivalent to multiplying the second line by $-1$, then adding it to the first line. However, the first operation changes the inequalities in the second line to
$$
-1\geq -3 \geq -5, \quad\text{or}\ -5 \leq -3 \leq -1. \tag{1}
$$
Adding $(1)$ to $1\leq 2\leq 5$, you now obtain the valid result
$$
-4\leq -1 \leq 4. \tag{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The reason inequalities are preserved under addition is that a sum of non-negative numbers is non-negative. So from $5-2\geq0$ and $5-3\geq0$ you get $10-5=(5-2)+(5-3)\geq0$, so $5\leq 10$.

But there's no such rule for the difference of non-negative numbers. The fact that $2$ and $3$ lie between $1$ and $5$ doesn't tell you anything about their relationship. This should be obvious from the fact that should you change the order of the inequalities, you get $3-2$ instead of $2-3$.

Comment: The in general, when talking about real numbers, neither adding nor subtracting inequalities like that is allowed, since I cannot be sure that all numbers are non-negative? Looks like the answer is yes, since had I changed $3$ to $-3$ adding the inequalities would also be wrong.

Comment: You can still add inequalities, because $a\leq b$ means $b-a\geq0$. So if $a\leq b$ and $c\leq d$, then $b-a\geq0$ and $d-c\geq0$, so $(b+d)-(a+c)=(b-a)+(d-c)\geq0$ and so $a+c\leq b+d$.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting is, by definition, adding the negative.
a- b= a+ (-b).

But if 1< 3< 5 it is NOT true that -1< -3< -5.
Instead, -5< -3< -1.